# BEM: Knowing how far to break down components and positioning components?

Tags: css, sass, bem

I have started to use BEM with a site I am styling. I am trying to understand to how to far I should be breaking down components (blocks). For example, I have a header that has a navigation bar in there. The header is classed as a block but the navigation bar in there could be a new block or part of the header block. What is best advised here?

I was hoping to find some example sites that implement this sort of thing to get a good understanding of it but up until now, I have found nothing that appears to demonstrate it.

I am also working under the assumption that the component should layout its elements, so this is great, a good candidate for flexbox. The problem I face now is laying out the component in the page. Imagine having to layout 2 components side by side, another good candidate for flexbox but knowing where to place the display: flex ? also wouldn't the component then be in charge of placing itself within the page by using flex item css i.e. flex-shrink, flex-grow, basis, order etc..

This means that the parent is dictating where to place itself on the page and it isn't 100% an independent block now as it needs a `display: flex` on its container.

I did [find some info](https://github.com/HugoGiraudel/sass-boilerplate/tree/master/stylesheets) with regards to file structure and wondered if this was something that could help? Maybe I am not fully understanding it - could the directory Layout be used for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the answers are on the https://en.bem.info.

> how to far I should be breaking down components (blocks)

https://en.bem.info/methodology/quick-start/#should-i-create-a-block-or-an-element

> it isn't 100% an independent block now

https://en.bem.info/methodology/css/#mixes

> some info with regards to file structure

https://en.bem.info/methodology/filestructure/

Answer (score 1):

This site uses the BEM methodology with Flexbox included.
http://fantube.me/